# How to fix "Invalid resource directory name" error on Android Studio v0.1.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I am getting the following error:

`Error occurred while compiling the application after compiling appcompat_v7 library`

This is the output:

> Gradle: invalid resource directory name:
>   C:\Users\Alireza\Desktop\Android
>   app\TISAppProject\TISApp\build\res\all\debug/drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi
>   invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\Alireza\Desktop\Android
>   app\TISAppProject\TISApp\build\res\all\debug/drawable-xxxhdpi
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':TISApp:processDebugResources'.
>
> > Running C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.2.2\aapt.exe
> >     failed. See output

How can I fix this?
I am running Android Studio v0.1.1 on Windows 7

Thanks in advance

Comment: Firsty update IDE, Android Studio is at version 1.2 (even 1.3 beta) at the moment...

Comment: I've updated  'compileSdkVersion' and 'buildToolsVersion' to API 21.0.1, then the above error was fixed. but now when I run it I get error "unfortunately, TISApp has stopped!". How can i fix it?